# strange error with CE image

Tags: export

I have two channels that use one custumfield group. One channel is for placing a entry without sign-up en the another with sign-up.

"melding_vrij" and "melding_login"

{exp:channel:entries channel="melding_vrij" limit="12" disable="member_data|pagination" dynamic="off" cache="yes" refresh="600"}
            {if afbeeldingen !=""}
                {exp:ce_img:pair src="{afbeeldingen}" max="80" quality="30"}
                    
                {/exp:ce_img:pair}
            {/if}
{tekst}
{/exp:channel:entries}

If I use "melding_login" it display all entry's but if I use channel "melding_vrij" it gives a blank page. If I remove the CE img tag it works fine. It always worked fine but suddenly it's not working anymore and I can not understand why

Answer (score 0):

Presumably then the issue is with the field `afbeeldingen` - are you sure it has a value defined in both channels?